# Formulas in Azimuthal Equidistant Projection

Tags: math, gis, formula

Given a location(lat,lng), I want to get its coordinate in an [Azimuthal Equidistant Projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection). The formulas are explained [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AzimuthalEquidistantProjection.html).

Below is the screenshot of the web  page.
[image: formulas]

at the end of that page, it states
[image: c]

It looks like given any location (lat [-Pi/2, +Pi/2], lng [0, +2Pi)), and the center of the projection (latCenter, lngCenter), I can calculate its coordinate (x, y) in the map, and since no map Radius is provided, the value of x and y will fall in the range of [-1, +1] or [-Pi, +Pi].

My question is, what is the **c** in the formulas? If it is a value calculated from (x, y), how can it be used to calculate (x, y)?

Can somebody help me understand these formulas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use equation 4 to compute `c` when projecting from lat/long to x,y.  Equation 7 is for computing the inverse, ie going from x,y to lat/long.  For your purposes, making a map, ignore equation 7.

`c` is the angle subtended at the centre of the Earth by the arc of the great circle from the centre of the projection (phi0, lambda0) to another point (phi, lambda).

Comment: Can you give an answer with the inverse, I.e going from x,y to lat/long I'm curious what this would look like.  I need this for the project I'm working on which goes the other direction and would greatly appreciate your help! I am just confused by what the sub 0 and non sub 0 means for reversing the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't state the programming language you're working with here is an implementation in F# from a recent [blogpost](http://www.samuelbosch.com/2014/02/azimuthal-equidistant-projection.html).

```
open System
module AzimuthalEquidistantProjection =

    let inline degToRad d = 0.0174532925199433 * d; // (1.0/180.0 * Math.PI) * d

    let project centerlon centerlat lon lat =
        // http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AzimuthalEquidistantProjection.html
        // http://www.radicalcartography.net/?projectionref
        let t:float = degToRad lat
        let l:float = degToRad lon
        let t1 = degToRad centerlat // latitude center of projection
        let l0 = degToRad centerlon // longitude center of projection
        let c = Math.Acos ((sin t1) * (sin t) + (cos t1) * (cos t) * (cos (l-l0)))
        let k = c / (sin c)
        let x = k * (cos t) * (sin (l-l0))
        let y = k * (cos t1) * (sin t) - (sin t1) * (cos t) * (cos (l-l0))
        (x, y)
```

[Other versions (F# with units of measure, Python and Julia)](http://www.samuelbosch.com/2014/02/azimuthal-equidistant-projection.html)